# SQL - How to Label Number for Each ROW & BLOCK

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, row-number

I have a table column like this

```
A, A, B, C, A, A, B, D, E, E, E
```

I Would like to label number for each ROW & block like this

```
(A, 1), (A, 1), (B, 2), (C, 3), (A, 4), (A, 4), (B, 5), (D, 6), (E, 7), (E, 7), (E, 7)
```

How to do? Thank you.

Comment: Which database are you using? Is it MySQL? Is it SQL Server? Is it Oracle?

Comment: MSSQL & PostgreSQL

Comment: Do you have a column the data is ordered by?

Comment: Just only have timestamp to be order. Even the same data in the different block, It need to be labeled for different number.

Comment: is current data ordred by timestamp??

Comment: Please read the first couple of paragraphs in the [sql tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: You shouldn't be storing comma separated values in the first place.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . .  I think that is just a formatting thing.  Assume that each value is a different row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have a table like this:

```
SELECT * FROM t ORDER BY ord

let, ord
--------
A, 1
A, 2
B, 3
C, 4
A, 5
A, 6
B, 7
D, 8
E, 9
E, 10
E, 11
```

If you do this:

```
with cte as(
  select let, ord, case when lag(let) over(order by ord) <> let then 1 else 0 end as letchanged
  from yourtable
)

select let,
  1 + sum(letchanged) over(order by ord rows unbounded preceding) as ctr
from cte
```

Then you will get:

```
let, ctr
--------
A, 1
A, 1
B, 2
C, 3
A, 4
A, 4
B, 5
D, 6
E, 7
E, 7
E, 7
```